# Does the QFT Klein-Gordon equation describe the state of the field or the field operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-states, klein-gordon-equation

In the canonical quantization of QFT we talk about:

- **states** representing a field.
- field **operators**.

The quantum Klein-Gordon equation is expressed in terms of the field φ. Is φ (**in the equation**) the state or the operator? And whichever the answer is, can you find a way to express the same equation in terms of the other possibility?

Comment: $\varphi$ is an operator  and the states of the free theory can be obtained by acting with this operator on the vacuum state.

Comment: Fields are not states and states are not fields. The KG equation governs the time-evolution of the field operators (in the Heisenberg picture).

Comment: @Tobias Fünke I talked about the state representing a field.

Comment: @Silas Do we obtain proper states from $\phi |0\rangle$? For the scalar field (solution to the KG equation), $\phi = \int d^{3}\vec{p} a^{\dagger}_{p}e^{-ipx} + \text{h.c.}$ up to a normalisation - what of the exponential factor that just remains?

Comment: @ShKol. "proper"? phase? what of it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am very new to QFT and I have just learnt that we define 1 particle states as $a_{p}^{\dagger}|0\rangle$ - since there's an infinity of such $a_{p}^{\dagger}$ along with the phase (which is also integrated upon) here, I was just asking what kind of states these represent.

Comment: They are superpositions of one particle states, obviously.

Comment: @Silas you are wrong: states of the free theory can be obtained by acting with the creation operators on the vacuum state. the field operator can be composed of many creation and many annihilation operators, and most importantly, does not only act on the vacuum, but on any generic state of the Fock space

Comment: @TrentKent6 of coarse you can act with an operator on a different state. Acting with an annihilation operator on the vacuum annihilates it per definition so there is no difference between acting with $\varphi$ or a superposition of creation operators on the vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

The free fields are a repackaging of an infinity of de-coupled (normal mode) oscillator operators $a_{\vec p}$,
$$
\phi(\vec x,t)= \int\!\!\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3 \sqrt{2\sqrt{m^2+|\vec p|^2}}} ~
e^{it \sqrt{m^2+|\vec p|^2} -\vec p\cdot \vec x } ~a^\dagger _{\vec p} +\mathrm {h.c.}
$$
in a Lorentz-invariant manner (which you are not asking about), with coefficients specifically chosen in the packaging so these fields obey the K-G equation, manifestly.

The states of the theory consist of infinite products of powers of such oscillators acting on the vacuum, $|0\rangle$, of any and all types (momenta, $ \vec p$): the Fock space. In general, they have no clue about the K-G equation, as they lack the variables it controls, anymore than oil paints have any clue about the Mona Lisa. The K-G equation relates and circumscribes the field operators.

Nevertheless, if you construct states by operating on the vacuum  with such quantum fields which depend on *t* and $\vec x$s, those states will naturally reflect the above arrangement, Lorentz invariance, symmetries, and K-G time-evolution outlined above, in general in a complicated manner of your design.  For example, the state $\phi |0\rangle$ will trivially satisfy the K-G equation. Why do you care?